# iOS Provisioning Profile Validation Errors

Tags: ios, certificate, profile, identity

I am trying to create a development provisioning profile for my application.

I have a valid certificate in the app center and in my MacBook it also shows that certificate as valid.

I have also added my device in the app center.

I have created a development profile related to the certificate that I created before and it shows up as valid in the app center. When I refresh the provisioning profiles page in the organizer however, the provisinging profile shows the status "Valid Signing Identity not Found". I have deleted and created the profile multiple times but the same problem is repeating.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the ***private key*** that is paired with the certificate you have.

Open ***Keychain Access*** and see if you can expand the certificate.

If you can't, it means you don't have the private key. If you don't know where the private key is, you'll have to revoke the current certificate and re-generate one, which will give you the private key.

Comment: I revoked the previous on and I regenerated a new one however, I am unable to expand this new certificate either.

Comment: I am unable to expand the certificate but the problem was solved. Thanks!